# Calling PHP file using Ajax

Tags: javascript, performance, datetime, ajax

I like to know if there will be any performance issue if an `xmlhttp` object is created every time.  For example, in the below code:

```
function currentTime(){
    var obj = null; 

    if(window.XMLHttpRequest){
        obj = new XMLHttpRequest();
    } else {
        obj = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }                                   

    obj.open("GET", "current_time.php", true);
    obj.send(null);                                 
    obj.onreadystatechange = function(){

        if(obj.readyState == 4 && obj.status == 200){
            var element = document.getElementById("current_time");
            element.innerHTML = obj.responseText;
        }                       
    };
}


setInterval("currentTime();", 1000);
```

or

```
var obj = null;                             
function createObj(){
    if(window.XMLHttpRequest){
        obj = new XMLHttpRequest();
    } else {
        obj = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
     }                                  
}

function currentTime(){
     obj.open("GET", "current_time.php", true);
     obj.send(null);                                    
     obj.onreadystatechange = function(){

        if(obj.readyState == 4 && obj.status == 200){
            var element = document.getElementById("current_time");
            element.innerHTML = obj.responseText;
        }                       
    };
}

createObj();
setInterval("currentTime();", 1000);
```

In the first example, the `XMLHttpRequest` object is created every time (1 sec).

In the second example, the object is created once.

Comment: You can call the timeout as `setInterval(currentTime, 1000);` to pass the function reference and avoid implicit eval.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

But the second version has problems also because the `obj` variable is in the global namespace. It might be a good idea to abstract this into a function which contains a reference to the `XMLHttpRequest` object, and avoids polluting globals as in the first example.

```
var CurrentTime = function() {
    this.requestObj = (window.XMLHttpRequest) ? new XMLHttpRequest() : new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    this.element = document.getElementById("current_time");
};

CurrentTime.prototype.get = function() {
    var self = this;
    this.requestObj.open("GET", "current_time.php", true);
    this.requestObj.send(null);                            
    this.requestObj.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (self.requestObj.readyState == 4 && self.requestObj.status == 200) {
            self.element.innerHTML = self.requestObj.responseText;
        }                       
    };
};

var currentTime = new CurrentTime();
setInterval(currentTime.get.apply(currentTime), 1000);
```

You could also pass the location of the PHP file to this `CurrentTime` function for further abstraction, however I think this is good as is. The `apply` method is used to set the context of the method to the `currentTime` variable and not the window, so that you don't get TypeErrors. :)